# A martingale stopped at a stopping time

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

By defenition a martingale is a sequence of random variables. And there is a statement which says that **a martingale stopped at a stopping time is a martingale**. But the last is a one random variable, not a sequence. Where am I wrong?

Comment: The statement is talking about the process $(X_{\min\{n,\tau\}})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ (resp. $(X_{\min\{t,\tau\}})_{t \geq 0}$ in the continuous time setting).

Comment: For a discrete time martingale M, given a stopping time $T$, the stopped martingale is the process $N_k = M_{\min(k,T)} $. This way it is a sequence in k.

Comment: Thank you, Gautam

Comment: @GautamShenoy: That looks like an answer to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've already answered this in comments. But not just for martingales, the stopped version of any stochastic process $X_t$ is given by $X_{t\wedge T} = X_{\min\{t, T\}}$ for a stopping time $T$. Usually to make sense, the process $X_t$ is assumed to be adapted to some filtration $\mathcal{F}_t$ and the stopping time $T$ is defined wrt this filtration.